# How to do a time comparison in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, time, comparison

I want to compare a time. I have a table with each cell header as 1pm to 1 pm, 1pm to 2pm, 2pm to 3 pm etc. So totally 24 rows for 24 hours in day.

If user input the value 8.25 pm, it should be displayed inside the cell 8pm to 9pm.

Answer (score 0):

`[date1 compare:date2]` will return if `date1` is earlier than, later than or at the same time  as `date2`. (`date1` and `date2` should be instances of `NSDate`).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you hold you time :-) Is it unix epoch or nsdate or what?

I'd suggest to take a look at THCalendarInfo from Scott Stevenson (http://theocacao.com/document.page/389). This class really helps.